# Are there American cars faster than NASCAR cars?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

In B specs I'm trying to win an American championship that only allows American cars.

I've tried with a Pilot Level 30 and a NASCAR car, but he can't win.

I'm wondering if there is any American car faster (or with more performance points) than the NASCAR cars to use in this race?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GT5 Cars website](http://gt5cars.net/cars) lists all the cars in GT5 and allows you to search on particular criteria. Search for cars from the United States and then sort the results by P/W (power to weight ratio).

I'd suggest picking one of the Chaparral cars or one the Ford GT LM cars, as they're MR layout which should handle better than FR.

Comment: I would like upvote twice :)

Comment: The NASCAR cars are built for going very fast in a straight line, they don't do so good when it comes to braking around corners.

Answer (score 0):

Get a fully tuned Ford GT, Corvette or Dodge Viper ACR edition. Add 50Kg to the ballast and shift it to the front of the car to help with braking and cornering! Play around with the suspension if need be.

Answer (score -1):

Chevy Corvette ZR-1 (C6) - With Race Mod and Race Medium/Soft tires.